# Error SQL Server 2005 Using Proxy to run Agent Job ConnGetProxyPassword

Tags: sql-server-2005, proxy, sql-server

I'm using a proxy to run several SQL Server agent jobs.
Essentially the jobs copy data from Excel spreadsheets into a dbs via a network shared drive.
The jobs have been failing for several weeks with the following error:

"Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Error authenticating proxy SERVERNAME\sharename, system error: ConnGetProxyPassword).  The step failed."

when I run it under the proxy account, if I run it under the SQL Server Agent then I don't have permission errors.

I've recreated the proxy accounts but this has made no difference.  The password for the proxy is correct.

Banging my head against this - any suggestions?  It's not password length which I've seen suggested online.

Comment: I suspect now, after two solid days of investigation that our dba changed the account that the SQL Server Agent runs under and as a result, the account can no longer use the proxy account I've set up.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL Server Agent account back!

Comment: If this resolved the issue, please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.